# How can I build with NODE_ENV=development environment in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I want to build with NODE_ENV=development environment in Next.js.

I have `.env.development`, `.env.production` in my project.

When I write the command line `npm run build:dev` in my terminal,
`Loaded env from {projectName}/.env.production` is output.

How can I build with not production but development environment?

Here is my `package.json` and `next.config.js`

please help me....Thank you.

- package.json

  ```html
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "next -p 3000",
      "build:dev": "cross-env ANALYZE=true NODE_ENV=development next build",
      "build:prod": "cross-env ANALYZE=true NODE_ENV=production next build",
      "start:dev": "cross-env ANALYZE=true NODE_ENV=development next start -p 3000",
      "start:prod": "cross-env ANALYZE=true NODE_ENV=production next start -p 3000"
    },
  ```
- next.config.js

```html
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      withBundleAnalyzer,
      {
        compress: true,
        webpack(config) {
          const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
          return {
            ...config,
            mode: prod ? 'production' : 'development',
            devtool: prod ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'eval',
            plugins: [...config.plugins],
          };
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      withImages,
      {
        inlineImageLimit: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
  {
    webpack(config) {
      return {
        ...config,
      };
    },
  },
);
```

Comment: Obviously you’re doing this temporarily, for what reason I do not know. I would just keep a copy of the prod.env file somewhere else and simply put your dev.env keys in the prod.env file. Otherwise if you want to configure your production environment to dev.env keys then that’s entirely against convention as far as I’m aware. Good luck!